# LeetCode #849: Maximize Distance to Closest Person

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem in the link below from LeetCode:

> [LeetCode: #849](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximize-distance-to-closest-person/description/)

But, I ask because I don't understand some `edge case` below:

> **Input**: `[1, 0, 0, 1]`
>
> **Expected**: `1`

I believe the rule returns the result value as shown below:

- [Figure #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msRBD.png)

The following image shows my `edge case` outcome based on the preceding rule:

- [Figure #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiqk5.png)

Based on the rules shown in **Figure #1**, Alex must sit in the seat with index `1` or `2` in **Figure #2**.

In such situation, Alex's **neighbor's maximum distance** should be `2`.

However, the expected answer is that the maximum distance is `1`.

Can anyone explain why the max distance has to be `1`?

Comment: it says `the closest`, take a 5-minute walk, then you'll surely get it. Attention is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Alex wants to sit in the seat such that the distance between him and the **closest** person to him is maximized."

```
[1, [0], 0, 1]
Closest to is to the left.

[1, 0, [0], 1]
Closest is to the right.
```